# Joining of two tables with group by and count

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I got User and Transaction tables and below is the structure of those tables.

User Table

username,transactioncode are the fields

Transaction Table

rolename,transactioncode are the fields

I have to get username,transactioncode from User table and combination of those two fields should be distinct and should get the count of rolename for that particular transaction code from Transaction Table.

Below is my query which is returning wrong count:

```
select u.username,u.transactioncode,count(t.rolename) 
from user u,transaction t 
where u.transactioncode=t.transactioncode 
group by u.username,u.transactioncode;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use proper explicit `join` syntax and other is to use `distinct`

```
select u.username,u.transactioncode,count(distinct t.rolename) roles
from user u 
inner join transaction t on u.transactioncode=t.transactioncode 
group by u.username, u.transactioncode;
```

In other way, you could also use *subquery*

```
select username, transactioncode, 
      (select count(distinct rolename) from Transaction 
       where transactioncode = u.transactioncode) as roles
from user u;
```

However, `distinct` may be redundant here but i don't know how your tables are looks and what data are into.

You could also first do aggregation and `join` with `user` table

```
select u.username, u.transactioncode, t.roles  
from (select transactioncode, count(distinct rolename) roles
      from Transaction t
      group by transactioncode) t 
inner join user u on 
           u.transactioncode = t.transactioncode;
```

Comment: Hi Yogesh your solution worked for me.Is there a way that i can display the user information even if the count(distinct rolename) value is 0?

Comment: @GrailsLearner... Use `left join` instead.

Comment: Thanks once again.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
select u.username,u.transactioncode,count(t.rolename) 
from user u inner join transaction t 
on u.transactioncode=t.transactioncode 
group by u.username,u.transactioncode;
```

Comment: okay, try removing u.username from group by in the above query

Answer (score -1):

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from HAPostingHighAmount where User='" & txtUser.Text & "' UNION ALL Select * from LAPostingLowAmount where User='" & txtUser.Text & "'", con)
```